# Cross domain calls / JSONP with WCF .NET3.5

Tags: wcf, c#-4.0, cross-domain, jsonp

I want to call cross domain service, I am using  WCF target framework  .NET 3.5, .NET 3.5 does not support crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled tag in web.config.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look on the following [implementation](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Implementing-CORS-support-c1f9cd4b)